# I have no arrays but I get "Array to string conversion" in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I get the error "Array to string conversion" on the mysql("INSERT") line and I have `var_dump`ed every variable that's being used. Here is the full error:

> Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\newresident.php on line 33

However I do not see any arrays and only see strings. Could this be a problem with having @ in the email variable?

```
<?php
include 'dbinfo.php';
include 'updateinsert.php';

$escapedPost = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

    $firstname       = $escapedPost['fName'];
    $lastname        = $escapedPost['lName'];
    $password1       = sha1($escapedPost['password1']);
    $gender          = $escapedPost['gender'];
    $address1        = $escapedPost['address1'];
    $address2        = $escapedPost['address2'];
    $city            = $escapedPost['city'];
    $state           = $escapedPost['state'];
    $zip             = $escapedPost['zip'];
    $hPhone          = $escapedPost['hPhone'];
    $cPhone          = $escapedPost['cPhone'];
    $wPhone          = $escapedPost['wPhone'];
    $email           = $escapedPost['email'];
    $pEmail          = $escapedPost['pEmail'];

echo $password1;
var_dump($firstname);
var_dump($lastname);
var_dump($password1);
var_dump($gender);
var_dump($address1);
var_dump($address2);
var_dump($city);
var_dump($state);
var_dump($zip);
var_dump($hPhone);
var_dump($cPhone);
var_dump($wPhone);
var_dump($email);
var_dump($pEmail);

mysql_query("CALL sp_User('$email', '$pEmail','$password1', 'Resident')");
//uiUser($hospitalemail,$personalemail,$password,"Resident");
$userid = getUserByEmail($_POST['email']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO ResidentInfo(UserId, NameFirst, NameLast, NameMiddle, Gender, Photo, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, PhoneNumberHome, PhoneNumberWork, PhoneNumberCell) VALUES ('$userid', '$firstname', '$lastname', NULL,'$gender', NULL, '$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$zip','$hPhone','$wPhone','$cPhone')");

?>
```

Output:

```
string(6) "Fname"
string(4) "Lname"
string(40) "cd889c90136db988312a7953bbbbac980de23b03"
string(1) "M"
string(14) "24 Olive Ln."
string(0) ""
string(10) "Kearny"
string(10) "New Jersey"
string(10) "0710907109"
string(15) "e73879728812345"
string(15) "e73879728812345"
string(15) "e73879728812345"
string(15) "worki@yahoo.com"
string(12) "wo@yahoo.com"
```

Comment: what is html element for gender ?

Comment: You `var_dumped` everything except `$userid`...

Comment: Wow you are right, $userid was an array with another array inside. Last time time I trust my friend's function at face value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstname       = (string)$escapedPost['fName'];
$lastname        = (string)$escapedPost['lName'];
...
...
```

Use string parser to make sure you are passing strings. Also use `is_string()` for checking.

Comment: What does casting to strings do here? If this is meant as an alternative to `mysql_real_escape_string`, it won't work - any malicious input in the strings will survive the casting perfectly fine!